# What's the difference between synced_blocks and synced_headers?

Tags: json-rpc, network, synchronization

My P2P is a bit rusty, but as far as I understand; if we're running a full node, other nodes will connect to us to share blocks. So I can see why it would be useful to be able to see how far behind other nodes's blockchains are with the `getpeerinfo` command.

However, what's the practical difference between `synced_headers` and `synced_blocks`?

For example, what does it mean if a peer has `synced_headers` equal to the height of our own blockchain, but a `synced_blocks` of **-1**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin clients can have headers without having blocks. (However, Bitcoin Core never has a block without a header.)

---

A `synced_blocks` of -1 means that the best block for the other node is unknown.

`synced_blocks` is set here:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/b3e42b6d02e8d19658a9135e427ebceab5367779/src/main.cpp#L557

```
stats.nCommonHeight = state->pindexLastCommonBlock ? state->pindexLastCommonBlock->nHeight : -1;
```

---

A `synced_headers` of -1 means that the best header for the other node is unknown.

`synced_headers` is set here:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/b3e42b6d02e8d19658a9135e427ebceab5367779/src/main.cpp#L556

```
stats.nSyncHeight = state->pindexBestKnownBlock ? state->pindexBestKnownBlock->nHeight : -1;
```

Comment: Thanks again, Nick. So would it be correct to say that if the nCommonHeight is -1, then the other node isn't attempting to send or receive block data with our node?

Comment: @inersha I think so, yeah.